# Yii hybridauth fails including "User.php"

Tags: php, authentication, yii, hybridauth, yii-modules

I'm trying to set up hybridAuth module for Yii. I did everything exactly as told in http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/hybridauth/ . Also did set up googles key ans secret. Trying to sign-in with Google the DefaultController tries to create a new User object but fails in Yiibase.php trying to include User.php (427). I'm using latest 1.1.14 Yii framework. The yii project is brand new and stock (I mean I haven't screwed up any standard components).

Thanks and let me know if I can get you guys any further information.

Comment: did you find your answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't needs the user extension. It's trying to access the User model, wich probably does not exists. Create a user table and the correspondig model to get it working.

As an alternative you can follow [this wiki](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/459/integrating-hybridauth-directly-into-yii-without-an-extension/) and do the integration yourself.

Comment: on file `hybridauth\controllers` on line `64` we have `$user = new User;`, one can use user extensions or have it's own user model

Comment: Thanx, that was the case. I'm not sure why I assumed that all the models and tables already existed.

Answer (score 0):

the extension is trying to use **user** extension(I didn't mean use, I meant reached for a user model),

try adding [user](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii-user-management/) extension to keep records of authenticated users.

UPDATE:

on file `hybridauth\controllers` on line 64 we have `$user = new User;`

here is what causing the issue, you can use user extensions or use your own user functions.

Answer (score 0):

Also I'd like to add that I's recommended by HybridAuth project to use Yii extension HoAuth. 
http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/hoauth/